# PDF files into wp-content uploads folder

Tags: database, wordpress, pdf

I found myself working on Wordpress.
I am recreating a site and I downloaded the backup to be able to trace all the contents.
Premise: that site no longer exists. All I have is the backup folder.

Now I ask you: why can't I find PDF files that were uploaded to the site (how do you do with images)?
Where are these files stored?

Answer (score 0):

In uploads folder, but you need to register them in your new WordPress website. Try to find script to register all medias.